# How do you find the line number of an error in C++ in vscode code-runner?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I am pretty new to VSCode. I use code-runner extension to run C++ program and strangely it does not tell me exactly which line caused the error. How should I know it?

For example the error message will look like this

/bin/sh: line 1: 87002 Segmentation fault: 11  "/my/path"

Comment: A segmentation fault is a run-time error, not a compile-time error. The line numbers are not available in the executable when it is just executed. Try using a debugger. I believe a debugger is provided by the C++ extension for VS code.

Comment: Are you working with pointers?

Comment: @jkb so that means I have to setup breakpoint and use debugger like gdb to find the error right?

Comment: @Ahmn21 yes, in this case it’s a linkedList

Comment: Basically, yes. Breakpoints are good when you have some idea of where the issue might be. You can also use the debugger to step through the code and watch it execute.

Comment: @artisan1218 the debugger's the right place to start. As for this question, either delete it and come back later with a [mre] and undelete it if you get stuck debugging or leave it deleted if you find and fix the problem. If the problem and solution is really interesting, add a [mre], undelete the question and self-answer. Right now there isn't much we can do with this question.

Comment: In your code, you are referencing to a memory location that is not initialized. (Next of a null which doesn't exist)

Comment: Handy trick for debugging linked lists: draw a lot of pictures to help you visualize the problem. If you have a picture for every step of a list operation, you can follow along with the debugger and should be able to see where the program did something you weren't expecting.

Comment: Unrelated: Coderunner's a bit basic. When you start making programs that consist of more than one file you'll have to update it to get it to compile more than one file. Once you have many file-programs, you'll definitely want to switch to a more efficient build system. My understanding is VSCode and CMake work together well.

Comment: Also worth noting: The location of a bug is rarely where you finally see the effects in the program unless you're looking very closely and printing a large amount of diagnostic information (or stepping through with a debugger). When a program does something drastic like crash, you'll often find the actual mistake happened quite a while earlier. It's good to know where the crash is, but it's usually just a starting point for further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you choose from Visual Studio Code the option `Terminal > New Terminal` and manually compile your source file with something similar to the following:

```
c++ -Wall -Werror -Wextra -g -fsanitize=address <your_file_here.c>
```

The compilation will fail if there is any warning/error/etc. caught by the compiler.

Comment: and `-fsanitize=address` will print out the line and other diagnostic information it can dig up about any dodgy memory accesses the program can spot. If you extend it to `-fsanitize=address,undefined`, the program will perform even more tests and possibly catch other mistakes.